# Split rows into even groups and give new group name

Tags: python, pandas

I'm attempting to split a dataframe into 3 random chunks. I'd then like to id each group in a new column, so that I concat these groups to other dataframes of matching group id's. Does anyone have advice about how to add this `new_group_id` column? Thanks!

```
shuffled = df.sample(frac=1)
result = np.array_split(shuffled, 3)

for part in result:
    split_df = result
    print(part,'\n')
```

Desired output:

```
col1 col2 new_group_id
a    1    1
a    5    1
c    2    1
b    6    1

b    7    2
d    0    2
d    5    2
e    8    2

b    2    3
f    9    3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enumerate` with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) :

```
result = [x.assign(new_group_id = i) for i, x in enumerate(np.array_split(shuffled, 3), 1)]
```

Or if need loop:

```
for i, x in enumerate(result, 1):
    part = x.assign(new_group_id = i)
    print(part,'\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I'm receiving a syntax error at the bracket of your non-loop suggestion and an attribute error ('list' object has no attribute 'assign') for your loop suggestion. Do you have advice on how I can edit the code?

Comment: @psychcoder - There was my typos, not it is correct.